# What is the fastest way to read large csv file in PHP?

Tags: php, csv, large-files

There are some csv files in the server. Those csv files are created every minute.
The goal is to read the last created csv file and make a graph. The csv file size could be 300MB or more, and the file may contain 500000 lines or more. My current code can read 25MB csv file which contains around 130000 lines, and it takes long time. If it gets larger file, it shows "HTTP ERROR 500". I have also checked the PHP error log. It shows, "Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)".

I have read few answers regarding this issue from stackoverflow. But it didn't solve my problem. So, how can I solve this problem efficiently?

Here is my code:

```
 ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
 ini_set('max_execution_time', '180');
 $dir = DATA_DIR . '/' . date("Y") . '/' . date("md");

// copy filenames to array
$files = array();
$files = glob($dir."/*.csv");

// sort files by last modified date
usort($files, function($x, $y) {
    return filemtime($x) < filemtime($y);
});

$baseFile = [];
foreach($files as $file) {

    if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        $baseFile[] = basename($file);
        fclose($handle);
    } else {
        echo "Could not open file: " . $file;
    }

}

$rows = array();
$table = array();

// create table columns
$table['cols'] = array(
array(
'label' => 'Time',
'type' => 'datetime'
),
array(
'label' => 'Temperature (°C)',
'type' => 'number'
)
);

// read csv file 
$csvFile = file($dir . '/' . $baseFile[0]);
// keep csv data in an array
$data = [];
foreach ($csvFile as $line) {
      $data[] = str_getcsv($line);
}

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
$sub_array = array();
// Returns date formatted according to given format
$date = new DateTime($value[0]);
$time = new DateTime($value[1]);
$datetime = new DateTime($date->format('Y-m-d') .' ' .$time->format('H:i:s'));
$datetime = $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
// converting an English textual date-time description to a UNIX timestamp
$datetime = strtotime($datetime);
$sub_array[] =  array("v" => 'Date('.$datetime. '000)');
$temperature = $value[27]/1000;
$sub_array[] =  array("v" => $temperature);
$rows[] =  array("c" => $sub_array);
}

$table['rows'] = $rows;

// return a json encoded string
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
```

Comment: You can try splitting the file into smaller file and then parsing each of them.

Comment: How would that reduce the total time?

Comment: When you get a 500 error, check the PHP error log to see the reason, and try to fix that. It may be running out of memory or time, we need to know.

Comment: If it's running out of memory, don't use `file()`. Use `fgetcsv()` in a loop.

Comment: It shows, "Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)".